# Prove that the line is parallel

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a non-equilateral triangle and $\omega$ be the inscribed circle of triangle $ABC$, which touches sides $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ at the points $D$, $E$ and $F$, respectively. Let $G$ be the point on the circle $\omega$ such that $\angle AGD=90^\circ$.
If $DG$ and $EF$ intersect at point $P$, prove that $AP$ is parallel to $BC$.

I'm trying to prove that $\angle CAP=\angle ACB$. By diameter of incircle lemma, let $AG$ meet $BC$ at point $X$, then $X$ is the point where the excircle of triangle $ABC$ touches $BC$. But I really have no idea how to start.

Let AG intersects ω at point H, then DH is the diameter of ω.

[image]

Comment: I've seen this question not long ago but I can't find it. Did you delete it?

Comment: $\angle APD=\angle ACB$ is incorrect

Comment: Some drawing https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyykq.png To prove the claim one needs to show that D,I,J are collinear.

Comment: Sorry I meant ∠CAP= 
∠ACB

Comment: This appears to be a reposting of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467408/unsolved-geometry), which you deleted yesterday.  Please do not delete-and-repost questions.  Instead, please edit the question.  When you delete-and-repost questions, you run the risk of having your ability to post new questions automatically suspended.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As can be seen in figure :

$\angle PIG=\angle IAG\Rightarrow \triangle PHG\sim\triangle AHI$

$\Rightarrow \angle HIA=HGP=90^o$

That is intersection of PI and the circle must be point H, because HD is diameter of circle and angle HID is opposite to it.Also AG is altitude of triangle APD. Quadrilateral JHGD is cyclic and we have:

$\angle IHG+IDG=180^o$

$\angle IHG+IHA=180^0$

$\Rightarrow \angle IHA=\angle ADG$

Therefore :

$\triangle AHI\sim \triangle ADG$

$\Rightarrow \angle AIH=\angle AGD=90^o$

which is competent with previus result.That is PI is also altitude of triangle APD. DJ crosses the orthocenter H, so it is also altitude of APD. It is also perpendicular on BC which deduces AP is parallel with BC.

Comment: Please tell what you used to draw the picture.

Comment: $\angle AIH=\angle AGD=90^o$ seems to follow from $DH$ being a diameter of the circle and Thale's theorem.

Comment: It's also a given of the question that $\angle AGD$ is $90^\circ$.

Comment: @AlvinL, I use Solidwork for drawing.

Comment: How did you know that P,H,I are collinear?

Comment: @UWU11, I changed the figure and added more explanation that shows points P, H and I are co-linear.